# Query ORDER with UNION

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have to do punt an "*" in a list of dates, like this:

```
*
1/1/2021
2/1/2021
3/1/2021
...
```

So, with my low knowledge, I created something like this code:

```
SELECT Disciplines_Date.Date_Modification
FROM Disciplines_Date
ORDER BY Date_Modification DESC;
UNION 
SELECT UnionTable.ABC 
FROM UnionTable;
```

where "*" is present in the table Union.
But, the command ORDER doesn't work and I've a sort system just by number, like the follow:

```
*
9/01/2021
3/01/2021
12/01/2021
21/01/2021
```

How can avoid this? Thanks for the help

Comment: Confusing. That sorting is neither a text nor a date sort. And what field is "*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to all, here some feedback:

select * from (
SubQuery1
UNION
Subquery 2)
) as ANYname
order by

This is working without "AS" and ORDER. If I put "AS name" and ORDER BY, the order will not work.

or

```
    select abc from 
(SELECT 1 as sl, UnionTable.ABC 
FROM UnionTable
UNION
SELECT 2 as sl, Disciplines_Date.Date_Modification
FROM Disciplines_Date  ORDER BY sl, abc desc)
```

Both working only in ASC Mode not DESC.
Anyway, thanks a lot to everybody.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now.
Try this:

```
select abc from 
(SELECT 1 as sl, UnionTable.ABC 
FROM UnionTable
UNION
SELECT 2 as sl, Disciplines_Date.Date_Modification
FROM Disciplines_Date  ORDER BY sl, abc desc)t
```

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't recognize the date as a date. It sort as a text format

Comment: Ascending order is working on that too. Do you need descending order only?

Comment: Problem has been resolved. Please check my revised answer.

Comment: @ValerioCampanini hope your problem has been resilved.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively you are trying to union two queries:

```
SubQuery1
UNION
SubQuery2
```

The result of Subquery1 is ordered, but the union operation returns a new set of tuples. Which no longer preserve the order of SubQuery1.

What you want is to:

```
select * from (
   SubQuery1
   UNION 
   Subquery 2)
) as ANYname 
order by  <whatever list of attributes>
```

This will guarantee that the order by is the last operation performed.